# Rotating right an array of int in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm

I've got an homework assignment:

need to implement a function (RotateRight) that gets an array of INT and a number:

```
int[] res = RotateRight(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, 2);
//so then res will be {5,6,1,2,3,4}
```

and return the array after rotating all of the items to the right according to the number that been given, In our case 2.

And I have to do this efficiently in terms of memory space.

my best idea is:

if the number that been given is x, to use a new int[] tmpArray in the size of x to copy all the last x items to it. then with a for loop to shift all the rest of the int to the right.
And in the end to copy the items in the tmpArray to the begining of the original array.

Thanks in advance for any advice or help

Comment: It sounds like your idea would achieve the desired result.

Comment: Have you tried actually implementing your idea?

Comment: If you passed 6 would you get back the original array?  Is passing 7 the same as passing 1?

Comment: Andrew Walters - thanks for the comment, i've fixed my question
Kevin DiTraglia - yes

Comment: Just do be pedantic you are doing a [rotate operation, not a shift operation](http://www.utdallas.edu/~dodge/EE2310/lec14.pdf). A right shift operation would leave you with an array of `{ 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }`

Comment: thanks Scott Chamberlain, I've fixed it.

Comment: Using a copy of the array is hardly "efficiently in terms of memory space". This can be done in-place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the beauty of the Linq langage to return an IEnumerable without dealing with array size:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get c = a mod (b) with c in [0, b[ like the mathematical definition
/// </summary>
public static int MathMod(int a, int b)
{
    int c = ((a % b) + b) % b;
    return c;
}
public static IEnumerable<T> ShiftRight<T>(IList<T> values, int shift)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < values.Count; index++)
    {
        yield return values[MathMod(index - shift, values.Count)];
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var res = ShiftRight(new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, 2).ToArray();
    Assert.IsTrue(res.SequenceEqual(new[] { 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4 }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! looks elegant

Comment: Note that for a right shift you can just use `%`.  You only need modulus for a left shift.

Comment: Looks nice and in the real world probably the best answer but creates a brand new array so not efficient as it could be. If you want to do this in place (no need to create a new array) see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Most memory possible makes no sense, you probably mean as little memory as possible? If so you should swap each item in the array using XOR, i.e:

```
var a = 2096;
var b = 842390;

a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

would swap these numbers.

**EDIT**

Code to do the whole thing in place:

```
    public static void RotateRight(int[] input, int right)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < right; i += 1)
        {
            RotateRightOne(input);
        }
    }

    public static void RotateRightOne(int[] input)
    {
        var last = input.Length - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < last; i += 1)
        {
            input[i] ^= input[last];
            input[last] ^= input[i];
            input[i] ^= input[last];
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    var arr = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    RotateRight(arr, 2);
```

As Servy points out, this is only for integers

Comment: That's a neat trick, but can you figure out which pairwise switches to perform in order the cyclical shift?

Comment: Also note this option *only* works for integer arrays; it can't handle any other kind of array.

Comment: This is particulary slow for big shift. In fact, for a random shift, this is a O(n^2)

Comment: @Cyril: I'm aware of that, this is just homework with the requirement to use the least amount of memory possible... No one said anything about speed

Answer (score 0):

Don't know C#, but here are two C++ versions, both in place, the first (`rotate`) does the minimum possible number of element moves by exploiting the cyclic structure of the rotation permutation, the second (`rotate_k`) just does `2*n` moves for an array of length `n`. In both versions it's used that rotate right by `k` is the same as rotate left by `n - k % n`, so they in fact do the equivalent left rotation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void
rotate (size_t k, std::vector<int> &a) {
    size_t n = a.size();
    k = n - k % n;

    size_t m = n;

    size_t i = 0;
    while (m > 0) {
        int t = a[i];
        size_t j = i;
        while (i != (j + k) % n) {
            a[j] = a[(j + k) % n];
            j = (j + k) % n;
            --m;
        }
        a[j] = t;
        --m;
        ++i;
    }
}

void
rotate_k (size_t k, std::vector<int> &a) {
    size_t n = a.size();

    k = n - k % n;

    std::reverse (a.begin(), a.end());
    std::reverse (a.begin(), a.begin() + n - k);
    std::reverse (a.begin() + n - k, a.end());
}

int
main () {
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    rotate (12, a);

    for (auto i : a)
        std::cout << i << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to figure out the final index for each element after rotating it k times rather than actually rotating it k times.
This worked for me:

```
for(int i=0;i<a.Length;i++){
        rotated[(k+i)%(a.Length)]=a[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample on rotating an array A right K steps:

```
    var splitPoint=A.Length-(K%A.Length);

    var result=new int[A.Length];
    int idx=0;
    for(var pos=0;pos<A.Length;pos++)
    {
      if(pos<A.Length-splitPoint)
      {
        result[pos]=A[splitPoint+pos];    
      }
      else
      {
        result[pos]=A[idx];
        idx++;
      }
    }

    return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

C# 8 now has [Indices and Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Rotate Right...

```
int[] r = t[1..].Concat(t[0..1]).ToArray();
```

Rotate Left...

```
int[] r = t[^1..^0].Concat(t[..^1]).ToArray();
```

in place of the "1" above, a variable can also be used: `int[] r = t[amt..].Concat(t[0..amt]).ToArray();`